# SQL - selecting rows where 2 rows must be the same

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I am very inexperienced with SQL. I have a table that looks like this:

```
Columns:   A   B   C   D   E
           foo bar 1   2   3
           foo bar 4   5   6
           foo bar 7   8   9
           xyz abc 3   2   1
           xyz abc 6   5   4
           xyz abc 9   8   7
```

Now I want to be able to form a string like so:

```
"foo bar: 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9"
"xyz abc: 3   2   1   6   5   4   9   8   7"
```

If it matters I also have a list of the A and B columns I can use naively by going:

```
Rs1 = SELECT * FROM PARENT_TABLE:
    for a, b in RS1
        String = a + b
        Rs2 = SELECT C, D, E FROM CHILD_TABLE WHERE A='a' AND B='b'
            for every row in Rs:
                String += C D E
        print String
```

Is there anyway to do this WITHOUT having to iterate through the parent table and then on each row form a statement and thus iterate on that one as well. Am I missing an obvious solution?

Comment: Please provide your actual schema. What database are you using?

Comment: There is, but first are there *exactly* 3 rows for each A B combo?

Comment: @Bohemian: No, but the parent table also has a field representing the count. So the parent table will have A B Repeat Count as it's columns.

Comment: @RedFilter I am using Oracle 10g.

Comment: What determines the order of the rows to be used in the C D E  values? eg, is it in order of C lowest to highest left to right?

Comment: No order, just the order in the DB. I ended up doing the pseudo code I have in the OP. Works well enough, but performance could be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look up aggregate functions:

- [PostgreSQL: array_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)
- [MySQL: group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)
- [Oracle 11g: listagg](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm)
- [Oracle 10g: listagg](http://www.dautkhanov.com/2010/08/listagg-alternative-in-10g.html) (workaround)
- [Oracle: group_concat](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1318182&page=12) (workaround)

Comment: According to comments OP is using Oracle 10g.

Comment: Sorry vol7ron I need Oracle compatible.

Comment: Check out the 10g workaround.  I also added `oracle10g` to your question tag, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this up without actual knowledge of the schema, so it may not work as is:

```
SELECT A || ' ' || B || ': ' || WM_CONCAT(D || ' ' || E || ' ' || F || ' ')
  FROM PARENT_TABLE PT 
  INNER JOIN CHILD_TABLE CT ON CT.A=PT.A AND CT.B=PT.B
  GROUP BY (PT.A,PT.B)
```

If you need to ensure you have at least 2 rows included, add:

```
  HAVING COUNT(PT.A,PT.B)>=2
```

Answer (score 0):

if your table contains 20 rows out of them 2 are same

then you can retrieve the data

by simply writing

```
select * from tablename where column_name='common value of that column';
```